# WHILE loop in a WHERE query

Tags: sql-server

I have a questions concerning a WHERE query.

I want to insert information into a temporary table using something like

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable (ID1 int, BG1 nvarchar(max), BT1 nvarchar(max), ID2 int, BG2 nvarchar(max), BT2 nvarchar(max), ID3 int, BG3 nvarchar(max), BT3 nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO #temptable (ID1, BG1, BT1, ID2, BG2, BT2, ID3, BG3, BT3)
SELECT t1.IDB, t1.BG, t1.BT, t2.IDB, t2.BG, t2.BT, t3.IDB, t3.BG, t3.BT
FROM   #table as t1 CROSS JOIN #table as t2 CROSS JOIN #table as t3
WHERE  t1.BG = t2.BG AND t1.IDB = 1 AND
       t1.BG = t3.BG AND t2.IDB = 2 AND
       t2.BG = t3.BG AND t3.IDB = 3
```

And the #table looks like

[image]

And the result should look like this

[image]

So far so good.

Now the problem is I don't just have three CROSS JOINS but for example 30 and in my WHERE query I need to check all BG's with each other. So not just three constraints but (I think) 435 constraints.

Is there a possibility to use WHILE loops in the WHERE query???? So that I can dynamically check the BG's??

Something like

```
WHERE
   BEGIN
      WHILE @i < 30
         BEGIN
            WHILE @j < 30 
               BEGIN
                  t(@i).BG = t(@j).BG
...
```

I hope u understand what I mean :D
Thanks a lot
T.R.

Comment: Side note: it looks you have a huge problem in your DB design if you need 30 cross joins to retrieve the data..... Concerning your problem - well, technically you can create query text using any loops and then execute this query text dynamically.

Comment: Are you sure you're really need all these tables to be cross joined? Probably some left/right/inner joins will solve the problem better. It's hard to say it exactly without seeing your data structure and understanding what actually you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok, one sec, I will create some small example table!

Comment: @Andy: How does the syntax look like for your idea to create query text in the loop??

Comment: WHERE t1.BG = t2.BG is effectively the same thing as a INNER JOIN.  You will only receive records that match in  both tables.  Can you provide more information, and perhaps some sample tables.  Could you provide a sample of the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't looks like you really need all of these cross joins here.

Here is equivalent of your query written using inner joins only:

```
select t1.BG, t1.BT, t2.BG, t2.BT, t3.BG, t3.BT
from   #table as t1 
       inner join #table as t2 on t1.BG = t2.BG and t1.IDB = 1 and t2.IDB = 2
       inner join #table as t3 on t3.BG = t2.BG and t3.IDB = 3
```

Is is less complicated, should take less time to execute and definitely takes less memory. Also in the case of such a query you don't need all of this "435 constraints" in "where" condition you've mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thats good. But still, if I have more than three IDB's then I also have to specify each INNER JOIN separately.. And thats what I try to avoid! Thats why I thought maybe I can use a WHILE loop in the WHERE clause?!

Comment: Even if you have to do 30 self-joins, it is much more better for them to be inner joins, not cross-joins + bunch of conditions. Since cross join is cartesian product of two tables - it takes quadratic amount of memory to get result. And in the case of 30 cross-joins it can be huge amount of memory.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. But still, I'd like to know if it is possible to use a WHILE loop in a WHERE clause.

Comment: As I've said - it is possible. All you need - is create query text and execute it using `sp_executesql`. It's up to you - how exaclty you're creating query text, for example by concatenation in while loops.